# How do I configure my MCE remote in Xenial?

Tags: 16.04, xbmc, kodi, lirc

My MCE remote is working in Xenial, yet no LIRC is installed. Everything works on it except the OK and the BACK button. What service is using it? and how do I configure it to fix the OK and BACK, button? Did Lirc get replaced by something else?

```
ir-keytable 
Found /sys/class/rc/rc0/ (/dev/input/event5) with:
    Driver nuvoton-cir, table rc-rc6-mce
    Supported protocols: unknown other lirc rc-5 jvc sony nec sanyo mce-kbd rc-6 sharp xmp 
    Enabled protocols: lirc rc-6 
    Extra capabilities: <access denied>
```

Update: I was able to get the OK key working with adding

```
# OK KEY (422)
0x800f0422 KEY_ENTER
```

to /etc/rc_keymaps/rc6_mce

and running ir-keytable -w /etc/rc_keymaps/rc6_mce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide fixed my problem:

http://madaboutbrighton.net/articles/2015/remote-control-media-player-without-lirc-using-ir-keymap

Especially adding the following to: /etc/rc_maps.cfg

nuvoton-cir     rc-rc6-mce     rc6_mce