# Use MCE Remote to launch a program in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: 17.04, remote

(How) is it possible to configure a button on a MCE Remote control to launch a program on Ubuntu 17.04? I'm using ir-keytable and have a customised /etc/rc_keymaps/rc6_mce file.

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/852971/how-do-i-configure-my-mce-remote-in-xenial

Comment: It seems that this was possible using irexec on Ubuntu 16.* and earlier, but is no longer possible on 17.*. Since the answer here to alot of queries is "you should upgrade to the latest 17.* to get the best support" this is pretty ironic, and a really good example of why that advice isn't particularly helpful. It looks like there are a few people on here who have had their IR functionality broken by the upgrade to 17.*. It looks like I need to downgrade to 16.* to get this feature :0(